# Como remover linhas duplicadas de txt usando php?

Tags: php, jquery, arquivo, txt

Bom estou criando uma `div` que se atualiza a cada x segundos e nela estou exibindo os usuários atualmente logados, porém o meu código está inserindo a cada atualização o mesmo registro. Há alguma forma de excluir as linhas repetidas?

Segue o código que estou usando atualmente:

```php
<?php
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$usuario = $_SESSION['user_name'];

//grava os dados no arquivo
$arquivo = fopen("usuariosonline.txt", "a");
fwrite($arquivo, "<p><img src='avatar/".$id_usuario.".jpg'/>".$usuario."</p>\n");
fclose($arquivo);

// pronto aki terminou de adicionar

$file_name = "usuariosonline.txt";

// transforma as linhas do arquivo em arrays
$lines = file($file_name);
// verifica se a linha não é um comentário (apenas se você queira adicionar comentários no file.txt)
foreach($lines as $key => $value){
    if(substr_count($lines, "#") == 0){
        $texts[] = trim($value);
    }
}

// retira as linhas duplicadas (se não for utilizar os comentário no file.txt, utilize a variável $lines)
array_unique($lines);

//abre o arquivo e o reescreve (se você não quer modificar o arquivo só ignora os códigos abaixo)
$file = fopen($file_name, "w");
fwrite($file, implode("\n", $texts));
fclose($file);

include('usuariosonline.txt');
?>
```

Ainda apareceu o warning:

> Warning: substr_count() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in line 19

Comment: Agora a pergunta ficou mais objetiva. Obs.: esse -1 não foi meu, já que você melhorou a pergunta.

Comment: Você pode botar para gerar um cookie quando o usuário entrar. Entao depois você coloca para só inserir novamente se o cookie não existir mais. Se quiser o código, pode falar e alterar seu tópico falando que também gostaria deste código para evitar confusões

Comment: rapaz quanto a cookies eu nao entendo nada, porem tenho essa duvida tambem em php, crio outra pergunta melhor? qual a pergunta que devo fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Você apenas colocaria para setar um cookie quando o usuario entrar na página pela primeira vez. Assim, você poderia colocar pra escrever o nome dele no arquivo de usuários online apenas uma vez. Pode colocar também um tempo para esse cookie expirar. É bem simples. Recomendei modificar o tópico, pois qualquer coisinha que não estiver de acordo aqui eles já dão voto negativo e ficam enchendo o saco.

Comment: Vou tentar criar uma nova pergunta, quanto as respostas eu to ligado hj mesmo fiz um desabafo numa das questoes que postaram mais ta valendo

Comment: @VictorEyer acho que você devia repensar nas suas palavras. Aqui não é lugar de bagunça. Se você não gosta de como funciona, não é obrigado a usar. Se tem alguma crítica construtiva ou sugestão, faça no [meta] e a comunidade vai dizer ou não se concorda com você. Quanto a edição da pergunta, acaba atrapalhando a resposta que já foi postada. As questões devem ser elaboradas adequadamente, para evitar este tipo de coisa.

Comment: falei sobre esse tipo de sua resposta tambem

Comment: @VictorEyer quando dizes _"eles já dão voto negativo"_ estás a excluir-te. A comunidade somos nós todos, __tu incluído__ :) Se houver injustiças envia um aviso para a moderação. Se vamos separar entre "nós" e "eles" vamos todos aprender menos sobre programação.

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando achei esse post [forum](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/128864-find-duplicate-lines-within-a-file/)

e realmente é muito simplicado o modo, resumindo

```
// ler no formato de array
$list = file('file.txt');

// array unique remove as arrays(linhas) duplicadas
 $list = array_unique($list);

//  escreve de volta no arquivo
file_put_contents('uniques.txt', implode('', $list));
```

meu codigo completo ficou assim

```
            <?php
    $id_usuario = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $usuario = $_SESSION['user_name'];

        //grava os dados no arquivo
        $arquivo = fopen("usuariosonline.txt", "a");

        if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // faca um lock exclusivo
        fwrite($arquivo, "<p><img src='avatar/".$id_usuario.".jpg'/>".$usuario."</p>\n");
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // libera o lock
        } else {
        echo "Não pude travar o arquivo !";
    }

        fclose($arquivo);


    $list = file('usuariosonline.txt');


    $list = array_unique($list);


    file_put_contents('usuariosonline.txt', implode('', $list));

        include('usuariosonline.txt');
    ?>
```

Comment: se tiverem ideia de simplicicar mais ainda é sempre bem vindo

Comment: O ideal seria nem colocar o dado no arquivo, em vez de eliminar as duplicatas. Seria melhor você ler o file antes, e em vez de usar o unique, tentar localizar o usuario. Se já existir, você nem grava. Outro problema da sua solução, é que se dois usuários diferentes acessarem simultaneamente, um deles não vai ser gravado. Teria que dar um _lock_ no arquivo antes de usar. Em resumo: 1 _lock_ no arquivo, 2 le o arquivo. 3 ve se usuário já está la. 4 se nao estiver, acrescenta e grava, 5 desfaz o _lock_. http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: Vale lembrar que array_unique() preserva as chaves do array. Poderia utilizar array_values() após array_unique